# Rename a local-only mercurial branch?

Tags: mercurial, bitbucket

I find a lot of questions about renaming hg branches that have already been pushed/pulled by other people, but I've got a situation here where work has been done on a set of branhces (10 in total) that all have the "wrong" name - wrong in the sense that the repo (on bitbucket.org) has restrictions on the naming of branches.

Any developer can open a new branch named `app-feature-xxxx` (where xxxx can be anything), but a boatload of work has been done by a new dev, and none of the branches follow this naming pattern (the branches are effectively the xxxx part without the `app-feature-` prefix)

Currently these branches are known only on his machine - they've never been pushed to BitBucket.org, nor pulled by anyone else

Can they be renamed in-situ, before they're pushed? Right now hg is attempting to commit his history to BitBucket with these branch names and it's failing. If the branches can be renamed before that happens, everything should be golden.. And there aren't the usual "but what about everyone else's history?" problems, because only one person has these commits..

The easiest I've been able to come up with right now is to clone the repo again, just make one `app-feature-lotsofupdates` branch, and then keep switching working copy in the original repo, and use a diff tool to apply the code from the original repo (with the wrong names) to this newly cloned repo, committing after every diff/copy - effectively a manual merge of all the various features into one branch (that will then be merged into production)

Comment: You can use [the Convert extension](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/ConvertExtension) to change the branch name attached to the commits. This does require sending the repo to another repo, so the easiest way to use it is to do a one-time conversion of the "bad" repo to a new "good" repo, then push from there, rather than repeatedly converting back and forth (though the latter is also possible).

Comment: If it does not solve, comment, I usually solve this in a more manual way.

Comment: If the branches don't include merges (basically straight-line changesets), you can use the `mq` extension and `hg qimport` the branch changesets into patches, `hg qpop --all` to remove them, `hg branch <newname>`, and `hg qpush --all` to  re-add the patches; otherwise, the `convert` extension is probably the only way to go.

Comment: You can use the rebase extension to move commits from one branch to another.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the convert extension to Mercurial, and the `branchmap` option.

> The branchmap is a file that allows you to rename a branch when it is
>   being brought in from whatever external repository. When used in
>   conjunction with a splicemap, it allows for a powerful combination to
>   help fix even the most badly mismanaged repositories and turn them
>   into nicely structured Mercurial repositories. The branchmap contains
>   lines of the form
>
> `original_branch_name new_branch_name`
>
> original_branch_name is the name
>   of the branch in the source repository, and new_branch_name is the
>   name of the branch is the destination repository.

The command line to do this would be something like:

`hg convert` `--branchmap branchmap.txt` `path\to\source\repo` `path\to\converted\repo`

[Documentation.](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/ConvertExtension#A--branchmap)